# Get one cell from passed column/row/range VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, arguments

i'm writing a user defined function for excel in VBA.

User may pass a whole column/row into the function instead of one cell. How do you get cell that is in the same row (for column case) and in the same column (for row case), where the function is.

For example, when you are writing in Excel in cell, say, C3 the formula "=A:A*B:B" it calculates A3*B3 in fact. I want to have the same behaiviour in my UDF.

Let's assume function that returns passed argument for simplicity reasons.
This code does not work (returns #VALUE! for columns/rows/ranges):

```
Public Function MyTestFunction(ByVal arg1) As Variant
    MyTestFunction = arg1
End Function
```

My option is as follows, but I am concerned about performance and the fact that user may want to pass a value to the formula instead of Range.

```
Public Function MyTestFunction2(ByVal arg1 As Range) As Variant

    If arg1.Count = 1 Then
        MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Value
    Else
        ' Vertical range
        If arg1.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Columns(1).Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 1).Value
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Horizontal range
        If arg1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Rows(1).Cells(1, Application.Caller.Column).Value
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Return #REF! error to user
        MyTestFunction2 = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    End If

End Function
```

How do you solve this problem?

---

Thanks to valuable comments code has been slightly updated and now can be used in other formulas to filter input values.

```
Public Function MyTestFunction2(ByVal arg1) As Variant

    If Not TypeName(arg1) = "Range" Then
        MyTestFunction2 = arg1
        Exit Function
    End If


    If arg1.Count = 1 Then
        MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Value
    Else
        ' Vertical range
        If arg1.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            ' check for range match current cell
            If arg1.Cells(1, 1).Row > Application.Caller.Row Or _
                arg1.Cells(1, 1).Row + arg1.Rows.Count - 1 < Application.Caller.Row Then
                ' Return #REF! error to user
                MyTestFunction2 = CVErr(xlErrRef)
                Exit Function
            End If

            ' return value from cell matching cell with function
            MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Worksheet.Columns(1).Cells(Application.Caller.Row, arg1.Column).Value
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Horizontal range
        If arg1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ' check for range match current cell
            If arg1.Cells(1, 1).Column > Application.Caller.Column Or _
                arg1.Cells(1, 1).Column + arg1.Columns.Count - 1 < Application.Caller.Column Then
                ' Return #REF! error to user
                MyTestFunction2 = CVErr(xlErrRef)
                Exit Function
            End If

            ' return value from cell matching cell with function
            MyTestFunction2 = arg1.Worksheet.Rows(1).Cells(arg1.Row, Application.Caller.Column).Value
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Return #REF! error to user
        MyTestFunction2 = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: In the first code snippet change `MyTestFunction = arg1` to `Set MyTestFunction = arg1`. Also add a small mechanism that recognizes the `TypeName()` of the `arg1` and make sure that the function is receiving a range. Then go to your spreadsheet and type in `MyTestFunction(A:A)` on any row and you'll receive the equivalent value from the column you're passing to the function that sits on the same row.

Comment: And your second idea about getting a similar behaviour as `=A:A*B:B` you can achieve with `Public Function MyTestFunction2(ParamArray arr() As Variant)` then on a new line `MyTestFunction2 = arr(0)` and close function `End Function`

Comment: Thank you very much for your first sentence in the comment. It make exactly what I need from the function. It seems it does not even need any further checks.

Comment: @mehow If you could convert your comments into the answer, I'd close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet change `MyTestFunction = arg1` to `Set MyTestFunction = arg1`. Also add a small mechanism that recognizes the `TypeName()` of the `arg1` and make sure that the function is receiving a `Range` type object.

```
Public Function MyTestFunction(ByVal arg1) As Variant
    Set MyTestFunction = arg1
End Function
```

example

[image]

---

Then, if you get to your spreadsheet and type in `=MyTestFunction(A:A)` on any row and you'll receive the equivalent value from the column you're passing to the function that sits on the same row.

And your second idea about getting a similar behaviour as `=A:A*B:B` you can achieve with

```
Public Function MyTestFunction2(ParamArray arr() As Variant) 
    MyTestFunction2 = arr(0)
End Function
```

example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `Application.ThisCell property` to do it. According to MSDN:

> Application.ThisCell- Returns the cell in which the user-defined
>   function is being called from as a Range object.

Let me present how to use it on simple example. 
Imagine we have data as presented below in column A:B and we want to achieve results which comes from =A*B for each row separately.

[image]

In such situation you need the function below and put it next in C column in this way: `=MyTestFunction(A:A,B:B)`

```
Function MyTestFunction(rngA As Range, rngB As Range)

    Dim funRow As Long
        funRow = Application.ThisCell.Row
    MyTestFunction = rngA(funRow) * rngB(funRow)

End Function
```

Please keep in mind that `Application.ThisCell` will not work if you call your function from other VBA procedure.

Comment: Thank you for this. Be careful about taking rngA(funRow) and rngB(funRow) directly, without taking a whole column first. This is because user might want to put a range like A2:A6*B2:B6 instead of A:A*B:B (users might me very unpredictable!). In this case funRow will be applied starting from second worksheet row, not from the beginning of the sheet.

Comment: @Eduard3192993, I know about it and I'm happy you know about that risk, too. Is this answer what you were looking for?

Comment: the answer I was looking for is the one that mehow gave me.

Comment: @KazJaw please note your function takes two parameters and has a hard-coded `*` multiply factor. This is not really a close behaviour to `=A:A*B:B`

Comment: @mehow, I agree, this is only and possible idea which could be incorporated into ones UDF. I really like your comments and I would be glad to up-vote it if you convert them to an answer.